# Modifying SQL Database on Shared Hosting

Tags: sql-server-2005, shared-hosting, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

I have a live database on a shared hosting server. I am making some major changes to my site's code and I would like to fix some stupid mistakes I made in initially designing the database. These changes involve altering the size of a large number of fields, and enforcing referential integrity between tables properly. I would like to make the changes on both my local test server and the remote server if possible.

I should note that while I'm fairly comfortable with writing complex queries to handle data, I have very little experience modifying database structure without a graphical interface.

I can access the remote database in the visual studio database explorer but I can not use that for anything other than data manipulation. I installed Sql Management Studio express last night and after 40+ crashes I gave up - I couldn't even patch the damn thing.

The remote server is SQL 2005 / The MyLittleAdmin web interface is available.
So my question is what is the best way to accomplish these changes. Is there a graphical interface I can use on the remote server? If not is there an easy way to copy the database to my local machine, fix it, and re upload?  Finally if none of the above are viable does anyone have links to a decent info on fixing referential integrity via query?

Sorry for the somewhat general question - I feel like I am making this far harder than it should be but after searching / trying all night i haven't gotten anywhere. Thanks in advance for the help. I really appreciate it.

...Also does anyone have a time machine I can borrow- I need to go kick my past self's ass for this.

Comment: Well, it might be a good idea to clone your current database, and test any changes separately first.

As for the time machine, theres always http://en.wikipedia.org/how_to_build_a_time_machine

Comment: That link goes to a deleted wikipedia page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually hosting providers allow you to backup and restore your database, so the easiest way to accomplish the move is to backup your live DB, download the backup file, restore it locally, do all the changes, do a backup of the local db, upload it, then restore it in the live service. Your site should be placed on an administrative shutdown during this time so it does not continue to update the data while you're doing this operations. You have to make sure your local SQL instance is exactly at the same build version (@@version) like the hosting provider, otherwise your local SQL may upgrade the database structure and you'll be unable to restore it back on the hosting provider (or you'll be unable to restore in on your local server if your version is earlier than the host's). The MSDN BOL has a detailed guid on how to [Copy Databases using Backup/Restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190436.aspx).

An alternative to backup/restore is to [detach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188031.aspx)/[attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx) the database, but I do not recommend this because you need to move both the MDF and the LDF in sync, and they're also larger in size than a backup.

This assumes you can do all the schema changes on your local copy in a wizardly manner, ie. fast and correct. Of course, that is not easy. The recommended way is to prepare in time a script that applies all the transformations needed to reach the new schema. There are tools like [SQL Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_comparison_studio.asp), [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm), [SQL Delta](http://www.sqldelta.com/) and other that can generate such a script. Also Visual Studio Database Edition can do this.

How I would do this would be like this:

1. Ensure I have exactly the same schema on my dev machine as on the live host. If not sure, I can take a backup of the live server and restore it localy. This would be my reference, v1. schema.
2. Keep the backup of v1. for reference
3. Start developing a script that changes the schema to my target. Sometimes I need to refresh my memory on script syntax myself, and what I do is I go to the SQL Server Management Studio wizards for the operation I want to do, select all the options in the UI and then select the 'show script options', that will show me exactly the script SSMS is running to accomplish my desired change.
4. For each change I add to the script, I can test it by restoring the v1. reference backup I have from step 1 and running the script.
5. Keep iterating on the script, adding one change at a time, until all the needed schema changes are done. After each change, I can test it again like in step 4.
6. Yourscript should do not only DDL changes to the schema, but also any DML changes needed (modifying reference data, changing values, moving columns between tabels etc).
7. When the script is ready, I can download a newer backup, apply the script, and upload the updated backup and restore it on the live host. Alternatively you can simply run the script on the live host (after of course you backed it up in case something goes horribly wrong).

In my projects I always rely on scripts to deploy and upgrade the database. In fact I use the database extended properties to store a 'version' of my application deployed schema and in my code I simply roll forward all the scripts that bring the schema to my last version. I have an article on my blog describing this technique: [Version Control and your Database](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/).

Comment: Thank you so much for all the info! This is exactly what I needed.